# Conditional "On the Fly" Column with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two tables I am working with; `tl_2015_us_county` which consists of county polygons, and `tl_2015_48_puma10` which consists of PUMA polygons. I am currently using the below SQL in order to achieve a sort of conditional assignment of the `Within` field which denotes whether the county is within the PUMA or vice versa. As an extension, I will need to do a conditional assignment of the `Urban` field which will be set to true if the corresponding county qualifies (probably based off of population density).

How can I achieve this conditional assignment without some sort of crazy number of nested unions and what not? I am not fluent with PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        tx_county.name        AS "County Name",
        tx_county.geoid       AS "GEOID",
        puma.pumace10         AS "PUMA",
        'TRUE'::Character(5)  AS "Within",
        'FALSE'::Character(5) AS "Urban"
    FROM
        tl_2015_48_puma10 as puma, 
        (select * from tl_2015_us_county where statefp = '48') as tx_county
    WHERE
        st_within(st_centroid(tx_county.geom), puma.geom) 
        AND
        tx_county.aland <= puma.aland10

    UNION

    SELECT
        tx_county.name        AS "County Name",
        tx_county.geoid       AS "GEOID",
        puma.pumace10         AS "PUMA",
        'FALSE'::Character(5) AS "Within",
        'FALSE'::Character(5) AS "Urban"
    FROM
        tl_2015_48_puma10 as puma, 
        (SELECT * FROM tl_2015_us_county WHERE statefp = '48') AS tx_county
    WHERE
        st_within(st_centroid(puma.geom), tx_county.geom) 
        AND
        tx_county.aland > puma.aland10
    ) as AggregateTable
ORDER BY
    "PUMA", "County Name"
```

As a side note, this code does work several orders of magnitude faster than my Python Shapely/Fiona implementation...

Comment: You are testing the centroid for containment. Would it not be better to use ST_Contains(tx_county.geom, puma.geom). There are some cases where the centroid is not even inside the polygon, eg, a crescent moon shape. Also, is it safe to assume that if tx_county.geom contains puma.geom, then this puma.geom could not contain a different tx_county.geom. If so, you could use a two step process, where you exclude those found in the first step (by aland, primary key?) from the 2nd within/contains query.

Comment: I must use the centroid because the data do not align perfectly, so sometimes the smaller geometry is not completely within the larger geometry. These sorts of overlaps cause either under represented or over represented data when using ST_Within or ST_Intersect. The nature of these particular data is such that the centroid will always fall within its polygon. aland and aland10 are the area in meters of the polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
﻿SELECT
    tx_county.name        AS "County Name",
    tx_county.geoid       AS "GEOID",
    puma.pumace10         AS "PUMA",
    (tx_county.aland <= puma.aland10) AS "Within",
    (tx_county.density >= 5,000)      AS "Urban"
FROM
    tl_2015_48_puma10 as puma,
    (SELECT * FROM tl_2015_us_county WHERE statefp = '48') AS tx_county
WHERE
        (st_within(st_centroid(tx_county.geom), puma.geom)
        AND
        tx_county.aland <= puma.aland10)
    OR
        (st_within(st_centroid(puma.geom), tx_county.geom)
        AND
        tx_county.aland > puma.aland10)
ORDER BY
    "PUMA", "County Name"
```

Interestingly, the tests in the SELECT had very little impact on performance, however, consolidating the two SELECTS into a conditional WHERE causes the run time to increase three fold.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could solve this with a case statement:

```
CASE WHEN st_within(st_centroid(tx_county.geom), puma.geom) 
          AND
          tx_county.aland <= puma.aland10
     THEN 'TRUE'
     ELSE 'FALSE' END AS "Within"
```

You would need to revise how the tables join, likely using `ST_Intersects(puma.geom, tx_county.geom)` that way you don't end up with the Cartesian product of the two tables and a whole bunch of "FALSE" values in your "Within" column.